# Filter in php/mysql with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I did one webpage with pagination in php. But i want to include some filter to search in this pagination. So if someone has good advice, will be good received.

Here is the file where i did the pagination. The name is, Index.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';
$database_connection = database_connect();
$title='hola';
$content='';
//user input
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$perPage = 2;
//Positioning
$start = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage : 0;
$art = $database_connection->query("SELECT id FROM coffee");
//Query
$articles = $database_connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM coffee LIMIT $start,$perPage");

$articles->execute();
$articles = $articles->fetchAll();

$resultado = $database_connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM coffee");
$fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = $fila["total"];
$pages = ceil($total/$perPage);

include 'Template_1.php';
?>
```

And here is my html website. Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="banner">             
            </div>

            <nav id="navigation">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tool.php">Coffee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="manager.php">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="content_area">
                <?php

                require_once("tool.php");
                foreach ($articles as $article):
                    echo $article['id'];?>
                </br><?php
                endforeach;?></br><?php
                for($x=1;$x<=$pages;$x++):?>
                    <a href="tool.php?page=<?php echo $x;?>"><?php echo $x;?></a>
              <?php endfor;?>
                    </br>
                     <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>

            <div id="sidebar">

            </div>

            <footer>
                <p>All rights reserved</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: WHERE CONCAT(`id`) - why concat when you have one column? And you fetching "id" column from "users" table and you calling variable "articles"... You put "1" as value of your "id" in input tag, it must start with letter... You must describe your question better, it seems to me that you are trying to combine pagination and search on same page but I haven't understand it from your question.

Comment: yes you are right i did the pagination very well. But i can't combine search with my pagination. This is my question only nothing more. I am little lost and for this i explain some steps that i did to get. I dont say that they are succesful or not. I am not profesional developer so i am only novice.

Comment: sorry if the post are not clear i change ok.

Comment: Look into using jQuery Datatables. They are very simple to integrate and provide this type of functionality out of the box, plus other cool features such as sorting on columns, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if i know what you mean by "But i can't combine search with my pagination." But as i understand you want to add some kind of a 'where' statement in your query.

Here are examples of doing it and i think the last code from this site is what you want: http://www.webreference.com/programming/php/search/2.html